# disable office access keys in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using [Keyman Keyboard](https://keyman.com/) for special characters that I need to use in an MS Word document (365).

The keyboard requires that I use the right side ALT Key plus specific characters (specifically, vowels a, e, i, o, u). I have the keyboard activated and it works properly in other applications like notepad, but in MS word rightALT+[key] activates "Office Access Keys" which opens a small tab informing me that I have selected Office Access Key and it does things like selecting menu tabs in MS word.

[image: example of Office Access Key message]

I can't figure out how to disable these office access keys, apparently you can do something like in a menu in the MS Office program, but I am using a student license of MS office, and I cannot actually install MS Office on my machine unless I 'go premium'.

I've gone through hundreds of keyboard shortcuts within MS Word's shortcut menu but haven't yet found the specific shortcuts that are getting in the way, and in any case I would have to find and individually disable 5 different shortcuts that may not all be in the same place.

I would like to know how to disable these Office Access Keys within MS word.

I'm running the 64 bit version of Office 365's MS Word on Windows 11.

Comment: This is built into Word at a very basic level and as far as I know cannot be changed. Consider for your shortcuts combining shift keys, i.e. Shift+Alt or Ctrl+Alt

Comment: These  Access Keys for the ribbon options are unabled to be disabled.